# Waiting for function but still no results

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to create two functions, one function gets two weeks and the other one creates a prompt where I want to display the weeks, this is what I tried:

```
let weeks = {};

async function getWeeks() {
    await sql.open('./weeks.db');
    sql.get(`SELECT * FROM weeks WHERE id = "1"`).then(row => {
        weeks.firstWeek = row.week;
    }).catch(console.error);
    sql.get(`SELECT * FROM weeks WHERE id = "2"`).then(row => {
        weeks.secondWeek = row.week;
    }).catch(console.error);
    sql.close();
}

await getWeeks().then(async function() {
    makeEdits();
});

async function makeEdits() {
    message.channel.send(new Discord.RichEmbed().setTitle(`Which week do you want?`).setDescription(` for **${weeks.firstWeek}**.\n for **${weeks.secondWeek}**.`)).then(async function(message) {
        // Both values are undefined here however I can use them deeper down into the function
```

I tried to await a function and then start another but it did not work as expected, what should I do instead?

Comment: You have to await the `sql.get()` calls too.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to also `await` the `sql.get` calls, and you could refactor your `.then`s to `await`s to improve readability:

```
 async function getWeeks() {
   const weeks = {}; // local scope helps to prevent racing errors

   await sql.open('./weeks.db');

   try {
     const row = await sql.get(`SELECT * FROM weeks WHERE id = "1"`);
     weeks.firstWeek = row.week;
   } catch(error) { console.error(error); }

   try {
     const row = await sql.get(`SELECT * FROM weeks WHERE id = "2"`);  
     weeks.secondWeek = row.week;
   } catch(error) { console.error(error); }

   sql.close();

   return weeks;
}

function makeEdits(weeks) { /*...*/ }

makeEdits(await getWeeks());
```